# Adding data in my sql table from tableView shows the same index value for all the cells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tableview

I have two sections in the table view and when user clicks on any cell it shows detail data but problem is that when user selects any of the option from first sections it shows index 3 and from second section then it shows 6 only i have 3 values in each section i want that when i click on index on it may shows index values not three last value

contentID shows 3 for all mean last values

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    userName=@"Jamshed";
    contentID=theCellData.content_ID;
    status=@"On";

    NSString*type=theCellData.content_Type;

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"Video" ]) 
        {
      [self playVideo];
    }

}




 -(void)addToLearning{


NSLog(@"Content ID Learning %@",contentID);


NSDate *StrDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *Dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[Dateformat setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS"];
NSMutableString *DateStr = [Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate];
addedDate=DateStr;


NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user_Name=%@&content_ID=%@&added_Date=%@&status=%@",userName,contentID,addedDate,status];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/myLearning.php"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

}

Comment: indexPath.row it gives u to index value of row

Comment: yes it is fine but problem is that i have custom cell and i have button on cell so when i click on that button i want that it should the content id of that cell of which button is clicked

Comment: you can tag for button and get it in selector method by "[sender tag]".

Comment: @iManan i have edited code please see my button code

Comment: @DeveloperIOS: try my answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492650/adding-data-in-my-sql-table-from-tableview-shows-the-same-index-value-for-all-th/15492851#15492851

Comment: Two sections are containing different data right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for Button on Custom Cell

Code ::

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   .......

   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   [button setTag:indexPath.row];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

   .........
}
```

On Click Method ::

```
-(IBAction)onClick:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Tag :===> %d", [sender tag]);

    ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
    contentID = theCellData.content_ID;
    NSLog(@"ID ===> %@", cotentID);   
 }
```

Hopefully, It may help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write following coed in your `UIButton` Tapped Method.

```
-(void) ButtonTapped:(UIButton *) sender
{
        NSIndexPath *indexpathNew = [self.tblView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];

      NSLog(@"%@",indexpathNew.row);
}
```

`indexpathNew` is return `indextPath` of selected button of cell.

Try my code i might be helpful to you.